# Proving that the period of $\cos^2x$ is half the period of $\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

For example, I know that the period of $\cos^2x$ is simply 
$$\frac{\text{period of }\cos x}{2}$$ That is: $\pi$. Could you provide me with both a visual intuitive explanation and an algebraic proof?

Comment: $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$.

Comment: Well if you know that $\cos$ has period $2\pi$ and that it's an odd function about the vertical line at $\pi/2$ then when you square the positive and negative parts give you the same shape, with half the period.

Comment: The specific cosine-ness of the $\cos x$ is irrelevant. What matters is that it's positive for a while, then negative, then positive, then negative, etc, where the pos parts all match, and the neg parts match, too, except for being upside-down. Each part is say, $w$ units wide, and since pos and neg alternate, the period is $2w$. For $\cos^2x$ the positive parts of $\cos x$ become *slightly-different-looking* positive parts, while the negative parts become *matching positive parts*, each still $w$ units wide. The new curve is now pos, pos, pos, ..., with no alternation; the period is only $w$.

Answer (score 2):

For all $x$ we have $\cos^2 (x+\pi)=$ $(\cos (x+\pi))^2=(-\cos x)^2=(\cos x)^2=$ $=\cos^2 x.$

If $k/\pi\not \in \Bbb Z$ then let $k=k'\pi +k''$ with $k'\in \Bbb Z$ and  $0<k''<\pi.$  Then  $\cos^2(0+k)=\cos^2k=\cos^2 k''\ne 1=\cos^2 0,$  so $k$ is not a period of $\cos^2 x.$

Comment: I don't understand the second to third line at all

Comment: @JiaoCtagon. Exactly what do you not get?

Comment: the whole thing from "if" to "then"

Comment: @JiaoCtagon . In the 1st line we show that $\pi $i s a period, so if $k/\pi\in \Bbb Z$ then $k $ is a period..... Now we want to show there are no other periods, that is, if $k/\pi\not\in\Bbb Z$ then $k$ is not a period. Let $k'$ be the largest integer less than $k/\pi.$ So $0<k/\pi -k'<1.$ So if $k''=k-k'\pi$ then $0<k''<\pi.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$f(x)=\cos^2x=\frac 12(1+\cos2x)$$

Period of $\cos x$ is $2\pi$ so $\cos2x$ has period $\pi$ and that is also the period of $f(x)$.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

We want period of $cos^2 (x)$  we know that $\cos^2(X)=\frac12(1+\cos2x)$ now consider only $\cos2x$ as the remaining are constants then it is in the form $\cos(ax+b)$ that is $\cos(2x+0)$ we know that period of $\cos x=\frac{2\pi}{|a|}$ now substitute $2$ in place of $a$ that is $\frac{2\pi}2=\pi$.
Then the period of $\cos^2(x)=\pi$